# Julia: get DataType from string

Tags: types, julia

I want to get a type from a string (from a text parameter file). I tried something like:

```
parse(DataType, "UInt16")
```

or

```
DataType("UInt16")
```

without success. Do I have to implement my own parser or is there already one in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about just `getfield(Base, Symbol("UInt16")) # -> UInt16`?

you need to make sure there is a `UInt16` type defined in the corresponding module though.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
julia> eval(Symbol("UInt64"))
UInt64
```

Note, however, that in general, using `eval` is not the best idea in the production code (especially if the string is dynamically generated). Of course - given your question - this is what you have to do, but if you want to be safer I would e.g. use a `Dict` providing the mappings you require to have only e.g.:

```
julia> s = string.(subtypes(Signed))
6-element Array{String,1}:
 "BigInt"
 "Int128"
 "Int16"
 "Int32"
 "Int64"
 "Int8"

julia> t = subtypes(Signed)
6-element Array{Any,1}:
 BigInt
 Int128
 Int16
 Int32
 Int64
 Int8

julia> s = string.(t)
6-element Array{String,1}:
 "BigInt"
 "Int128"
 "Int16"
 "Int32"
 "Int64"
 "Int8"

julia> m = Dict(Pair(x...) for x in zip(s, t))
Dict{String,DataType} with 6 entries:
  "Int16"  => Int16
  "Int64"  => Int64
  "BigInt" => BigInt
  "Int8"   => Int8
  "Int128" => Int128
  "Int32"  => Int32

julia> m["Int32"]
Int32
```

Comment: I agree eval is not the best idea, maybe getfield (other answer) is better. I am currently using the Dict implementation since it's more flexible and will allow me to extend to other names like "uint16" or "unsigned int 16 bits". But it isn't the prettiest I think ^^